# cyclic inference java lambda groupingby

Tags: java, lambda, grouping, java-8

I'm new to lambdas and confused with what I'm doing wrong in this line of code:

```
HashMap<Date, ArrayList<Trade>> groupTrades = allTrades.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Trade::getTradeDate()));
```

IntelliJ won't compile because of a cyclic inference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After a bit of pain I've worked it out and hopefully this will be useful to others as well

You mustn't use HashMap or ArrayList - just use the interfaces Map and List, code should read:

```
Map<Date, List<Trade>> groupTrades = allTrades.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Trade::getTradeDate));
```

Note that this rather generic message could be caused when any of the parameters in the groupingBy don't match what is expected in the declaration of the Map.

Comment: I have both `Map` and `List` interface but still I have the same issue

Answer (score 2):

try to remove the () on getTradeDate

```
HashMap<Date, ArrayList<Trade>> groupTrades = allTrades.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Trade::getTradeDate));
```

Here is a nice little overview: http://www.java8.org/

Comment: Tried that but still the same issue.