# Java collect function gives cyclic inference error

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

When typing the following code I get a "cyclic inference" error on the argument for the groupingBy function:

```
Map<String, User> mapByEmail = users.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getEmail));
```

I find this confusing because the following does not cause any problem:

```
users.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getEmail));
```

and neither does this:

```
List<User> listByEmail = users.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getEmail)).values().stream().reduce(null, (a,b)-> a=b);
```

So the question is, what is a cyclic inference and how can I avoid it?

EDIT Thanks for the answers. After further research I found out that I need to reduce my result by doing the following:

```
 Map<String, User> mapByEmail = users.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getEmail, Collectors.reducing(new User(),(a,b)-> a=b)));
```

Comment: `groupingBy` will create a `Map<String, List<User>>` not a `Map<String, User>`. It’s unclear why your compiler fails at telling you that in clear words… if you expect the email adresses to be unique, you can use `Collectors.toMap(User::getEmail, Function.identity())` to get a `Map<String, User>`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136533/cyclic-inference-java-lambda-groupingby?rq=1

Comment: @helpYou: The error message is the same in that question, but the code and the reason for the message is slightly different.

Comment: @Keppil , yes, this is why I didn't mark it as duplicate. But the URL is useful for him to see the type from the left side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your resulting type is incorrect. It should be `Map<String, List<User>>`:

```
Map<String, List<User>> mapByEmail = users.stream()
                                          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getEmail));
```

The error message looks confusing, but there's actual an error in your code.