# Converting Collection to LinkedHashMap with Streams API, getting "Cyclic inference" error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I need to implement a method that converts a `Collection<String>` into `LinkedHashMap<String, String>`,
in such way, that in the returned Map every `key` is equal to the `value`.

For example this list:

```
{ "one", "two", "three" }
```

would be converted into that map:

```
{ {"one":"one"}, {"two":"two"}, {"three":"three"} }
```

---

The solution I currently have is pretty straightforward - I'm constructing a new instance of the `LinkedHashMap`,
iterating through the `Collection`, and putting every `String` into the `Map` as both `key` and `value`:

```
public LinkedHashMap<String, String> collectionToMapJava7(Collection<String> collection) {
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    for (String s : collection) {
        linkedHashMap.put(s, s);
    }
    return linkedHashMap;
}
```

That solution works well enough, but since my project is already using **Java 8**,
I wanted to get to know the new features, namely `Stream` and `Collectors`.

Unfortunately I've run into a problem that's little confusing:

I'm taking a `Stream` from the `Collection`, calling a `toMap` collector, mapping both `key` and `value` with the same element,
and my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.4) spits out the vague "Cyclic inference" error on the marked line:

```
public LinkedHashMap<String, String> collectionToMapJava8(Collection<String> collection) {
    return collection.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(s->s, s->s));
}                                                       ̃ ̃ ̃ ̃   ̃ ̃ ̃ ̃
```

---

As far as I know after reading a couple of questions about this error, it usually strikes when you
[use a Collector with wrong resulting type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034307/java-collect-function-gives-cyclic-inference-error), but I cannot lower the type constraints and use a plain `Map` interface.

**My question is**: how can I convert a `Collection` into a `LinkedHashMap` with the Java Streams API?

Comment: Why you need a Map of keys and values that are equals? Can't you use a HashSet for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33724979/1743880 toMap return `Map`. You want to return `LinkedHashMap`, so specify your map with the mapSupplier argument.

Comment: It could be a bug in the IDE, I would try compiling it or using version 2016.3.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO especially since the OP knows they are Strings.